# tkinter combobox function not working when called in another module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, global-variables, python-module

Sorry,this may be a beginner question but i didn't seem to find my answer.

I have 2 python modules : **source.py** and **work.py.** I want to use **source.py** as a module where to define some tkinter functions and then use them  in **work.py**.

In source.py i created a combobox function that memorises the desired option in a variable called "e". Variable "e" is declared global.

If i run the combobox function in the source.py module as "main", variable e will be changed everytime i select another option from the combobox. It works as expected

However, if i import the combobox in the second module "work.py". then the variable e is not changed but remains at the initial assigned value .

How can i change the script so that "e" will get changed when calling combobox function from work.py?

My modules below:

source.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk

def add_combo_box(root,lst,row,column):
    global e
    def comboclick(event):
        global e
        e=myCombo.get()
        #myLabel = Label(root, text=myCombo.get())
        #myLabel.pack()
        print('e from combobox: ',e)

    # create dropdown box
    options = lst
    myCombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=options, width=40)
    #myCombo.current(0)
    myCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comboclick)
    myCombo.grid(row=row,column=column)

#when running here it works ok. Variable "e" is getting changed
if __name__=='__main__':

    root = Tk()
    e="x"
    options = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
    add_combo_box(root,options,row=1,column=1)

    def display():
        global e
        messagebox.showinfo("", str(e))

    btn=Button(root,text='show value',command=display)
    btn.grid(row=2,column=1)


    root.mainloop()
```

work.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import ttk
from source import add_combo_box
from tkinter import messagebox

# Here it doesn't work. Combobox is launching. Variable "e" is getting initialised with "y" value but after calling the combobox function it stays the same

if __name__=='__main__':

    root = Tk()
    global e
    e = "y"
    options = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
    add_combo_box(root, options, row=1, column=1)

    def display():
        global e
        messagebox.showinfo("", str(e))

    btn = Button(root, text='show value', command=display)
    btn.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I dont understand what your expecting to happen, in the second script. "__then the variable e is not changed but remains at the initial assigned value .__" What is the value of `e` you expect.

Comment: in the second script i want to change the variable e through the combobox  so that i can use it after that. And it's not changing. It stays at the initial value.("y"). But the same portion of code under "main" ...if I run that code in module 1 ( source)..there it works. Variable "e" is changing. The value e must change according to what i select in the combobox : one, two, three , four

Comment: So your trying to get the value from the combobox created in a function in another module right?

Comment: yeah. That's pretty much it. And i manage to get the value if I run the function in the source module. It changes the "e variable" with one of the combobox values. Unfortunetly it does not change the " e " variable if i run the same  but this time imported function in the second module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question remains a mystery to me, but I'm assuming you were having trouble with getting the value of the `Combobox` made in the function, inside of source.py. You could just return the `Combobox` from the function and assign a variable to it, and use the `get()` method on it, like:

```
def add_combo_box(root,lst,row,column):

    def comboclick(event):
        e=myCombo.get()
        #myLabel = Label(root, text=myCombo.get())
        #myLabel.pack()
        print('e from combobox: ',e)

    # create dropdown box
    myCombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=lst, width=40)
    #myCombo.current(0)
    myCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comboclick)
    myCombo.grid(row=row,column=column)
    return myCombo #return the combobox
```

Inside work.py:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    root = Tk()
    e = "y"
    options = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
    ahem = add_combo_box(root, options, row=1, column=1) #assign a variable to it

    def display():
        messagebox.showinfo("", str(ahem.get())) #use the get on the variable to get the value of the combobox made

    btn = Button(root, text='show value', command=display)
    btn.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Why did this not work with `e`? The `e` created in source.py and work.py are different and not the same. Indeed, I  think the right way to access the properties of `Combobox` is like I said.

Comment: It works if i put the combobox function inside work.py. Sadly i cannot do  that because  source.py serves the purpose for a bigger project will also have other functions in it to use as referrence for other "work" modules. So i can't repeat the functions in every "work" module i create. :)

Comment: @VoicuMirel You shouldnt. Just replace the function, with what I gave, in source.py. And do the necessary arrangements on work.py

Comment: it totally worked. Problem solved. Kindly Thank You